# How to know the websocket connection status in laravel 9 for pusher broadcasting

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher

Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to local.zts.com port 6001: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://local.zts.com:6001/apps/1407161/events?auth_key=9f72eeb7d24761835162&auth_timestamp=1656943955&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=5281128b393b7c73bb20514e675cf3d9&auth_signature=d033743a711c8372d8b5437f6296cf05b1a4c0f150e8a7136a3f3f17171b8ed4.

Comment: port 6001 is closed. Check their documentation.

Comment: Hi,
For me websocket connections and broad casting everything is working fine,
my question is if sometime php artisan websockets:serve command failed to run at the time wherever we are using broadcating that connection giving error and the apllication was broken,
so if websocket connection failed based on the connection status, we can stop to calling broadcasting functions (triggering events).
so here how to know the websocket connection status.
Thanks.